# How to catch all exceptions in try catch block in Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

How to catch all exceptions in try catch block in Xamarin.Android

I am very frustrated on how Xamarin.Android handles unhandled exception which is very weird, I added three exceptions for all api queries respectively:

```
try
{
   // api query using `refit`
   // json parsing using `newtonsoft`
}
catch(System.OperationCanceledException e)
{
  // user cancelled the query, show option to retry
}
catch(ApiException apiException)
{
  // theres an api exception , show error message to users , show option to retry
}
catch(Exception e)
{
  // unknown exception ignore , show error message to users , show option to retry

}
```

This try catch blocks works most of the time, but there is one certain scenario when our server is down, and it just throws exception and crashes the app over and over again until the server is back up.

This is the exception that keeps on bugging us :

```
Xamarin caused by: android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException
```

As you can see in [`JsonReaderException`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonException.htm) hierarchy, it inherited `System.Exception` which is the last catch block i used.

and I checked this `JsonReaderException` it extends from `Exception` , In which our try catch block should handle it.

Now im wondering is there any way that we can catch all those pesky unhandled exceptions?

Answer (score 4):

I'm getting unhandled exceptions in this way

```
    public void Init()
    {
        AndroidEnvironment.UnhandledExceptionRaiser += OnAndroidEnvironmentUnhandledExceptionRaiser;
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += OnCurrentDomainUnhandledException;
        TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += OnTaskSchedulerUnobservedTaskException;

        var currentHandler = Java.Lang.Thread.DefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler;
        var exceptionHandler = currentHandler as UncaughtExceptionHandler;
        if (exceptionHandler != null)
        {
            exceptionHandler.SetHandler(HandleUncaughtException);
        }
        else
        {
            Java.Lang.Thread.DefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler = new UncaughtExceptionHandler(currentHandler, HandleUncaughtException);
        }
    }

    private void OnAndroidEnvironmentUnhandledExceptionRaiser(object sender, RaiseThrowableEventArgs e)
    {
        AndroidEnvironment.UnhandledExceptionRaiser -= OnAndroidEnvironmentUnhandledExceptionRaiser;

        _logger.LogFatal($"AndroidEnvironment.UnhandledExceptionRaiser.", e.Exception);
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    private void OnCurrentDomainUnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException -= OnCurrentDomainUnhandledException;

        var ex = e.ExceptionObject as Exception;
        if (ex != null)
        {
            _logger.LogFatal("AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException.", ex);
        }
        else
        {
            _logger.LogFatal($"AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException. ---> {e.ExceptionObject}");
        }
    }

    private void OnTaskSchedulerUnobservedTaskException(object sender, UnobservedTaskExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        _logger.LogFatal("TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException.", e.Exception);
    }

    private bool HandleUncaughtException(Java.Lang.Throwable ex)
    {
        _logger.LogFatal("Thread.DefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler.", ex);
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Is there any chance I could show the user an error message?

Comment: @david, no, you could not